# Show that the map $L:M_{n\times n}(K) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_k(V,V)$ s.t. $L(A)=L_A$ is an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

OK, this is one where I am having trouble starting because I am not sure I am reading the question correctly to begin with. 
So start with:

$M_{m\times n}(K)$ denotes the set of all matrices with $m$ rows and $n$ columns with entries in the field $K$. Let $\beta \subset V$ and $\beta' \subset W$ be bases of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ respectively

Let $\dim_KV = n $ and $\dim_KW = m$. 
If $f:W \rightarrow W$ is a linear map then let $[]_{\beta \beta'}: \operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W) \rightarrow M_{n\times n}(K)$ denote the matrix representation map.

OK, the actual question:

Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(K)$ and let $L_A: K^n \rightarrow K^n$ be a linear map such that if $(x_1, x_2,\dots ,x_n) \in K$, (after ientifying this row matrix with the column matrix $X$) $L_A((x_1, x_2, \dots x_n)) = L_A(X) = AX$. Show that the map $L:M_{n\times n}(K) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_k(V, V) $ such that $L(A) = L_A$ is the inverse map of the matrix representation map $[]_{\beta \beta'}$ here $\beta = \{e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n\}$ is the canonical basis of $K_n$.

OK, this is where I am not sure if I am even reading this question right. It's asking to show that the linear map $L(A) = L_A$ is the inverse of the matrix representation map. So that means I have to take a linear map of any matrix, $A$, but I guess I need to find the matrix representation of the matrix? This makes no sense whatsoever to me right now, and it's getting more and more frustrating by the minute.

I understand -- I think - -finding a matrix representation if you gave me a polynomial or something. But this I can't even figure out where to start. Maybe there's a similar question answered on here and that's fine, but I wouldn't even know how to search for the thing. (Picture someone smashing his head against the table right now. I'm sorry to vent, but I can't be the only person who finds this frustrating).

Comment: ...in other words, you are studying the relationship between linear operators on $V$ and their representations through matrices, when a basis for $V$ is chosen. I think that you need simply to  recollect your ideas on 1) represent a linear morphism by a matrx 2) matrix transformation when the basis are changed.

Comment: I'm still lost.

Comment: sorry, not trying to be deliberately obtuse. This has jeust been one heck of a frustrating class to take.

Comment: you are definitly NOT obtuse. Linear algebra is tricky and deserves much time and attention. I will write an answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V$ denote a finite dim. vector space over $\mathbb K$, and $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$   any basis of $V$. We consider the following linear (iso)-morphisms:

$$L: M_{n\times n }(K)\rightarrow Hom_{\mathbb K}(V,V)$$
$$[\cdot]_{v}: Hom_{\mathbb K}(V,V)\rightarrow M_{n\times n }(K) $$

where

$$ L(A)(v_i):=\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ij}v_j$$

for all $A\in M_{n\times n }(K)$ and the matrix $[\varphi]_{e}:=B$ is defined through

$$\varphi(e_i)=B_{ij}e_j $$

for all $\varphi\in Hom_{\mathbb K}(V,V)$. We want to show that

$$L\circ [\cdot]_e= 1_{Hom_{\mathbb K}(V,V)} $$ and
$$[\cdot]_e\circ L= 1_{M_{n\times n}(\mathbb K)}.$$

- First relation, i.e. $L\circ [\cdot]_e= 1_{Hom(V,V)} $

For all $\varphi\in Hom_{\mathbb K}(V,V)$ s.t. $\varphi(e_i)=B_{ij}ej$:

$$L([\varphi]_e)(e_i)=(\text{definition of $L$})=([\varphi]_e)_{ij}e_j=(\text{definition of $[\varphi]_e$})=B_{ij}e_j=\varphi(e_i). $$

- Second relation, i.e. $[\cdot]_e\circ L= 1_{M_{n\times n}(\mathbb K)}$

For all $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb K)$ we introduce the matrix  $[L(A)]_e:=M$. We want to prove that $A=M$. By definition of $L$, $L(A)$ is the element of $Hom_{\mathbb K}(V,V)$ s.t.

$$L(A)(e_i)=\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}e_j.$$

Using the definition of $[\cdot]_e$ applied to $L(A)$ we have instead

$$L(A)(e_i)=\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij}e_j.$$

We put the two expression together arriving at

$$\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}e_j=\sum_{i=1}^nM_{ij}e_j\Leftrightarrow \sum_{j=1}^n(A_{ij}-M_{ij})e_j=0\Leftrightarrow A_{ij}-M_{ij}=0, $$

for all $j=1,\dots,n$ as $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ (and so the $e_{\bullet}$ are linearly independent). Repeating the same lines for all $i=1,\dots, n$ we arrive at

$$A=M$$

which is equivalent to $[L(A)]_e=A$.

Comment: thanks avitus. Looking at it, it seems a lot clearer and I am no longer panicking quite so much. (Gawd you should have seen me at my last exam).

Comment: @Jesse you are welcome. Exams makes people uncomfortable, that's their job :)

Comment: BTW the B you were using is the basis beta, yes?

Comment: I was using any basis $e$ of $V$. You do not need to use any specified one. Choosing different basis implies different matrices $A$, but their transformation rule is known.